# Frequency Histogram, For Loop

Tags: python, histogram

so I'll get straight to the point. I'm trying to make a histogram that takes numbers from a text document and makes a frequency histogram (0-10). I can make it work if I don't use a for loop but it's very ineffective. Here is what I currently have:

```
from graphics import *
import math

def main():

 #saying what the program does
 print("This is a program that reads a test file of test scores (0-10)")
 print("and draws a histogram with the amount of students with that score")
 print("raising the bar by one for each student.")

 #Get the name of the files with the scores
 fileInput = input("Enter the file name with the scores: ")

 #open the file with the scores and read the first line to get the # of students
 infile = open(fileInput, "r")
 stuNum = int(infile.readline())
 lineRead = infile.readlines()

 #Creates a window using the amount of students to base the height
 win = GraphWin("These Students Failed", 400, 400)
 win.setCoords(0,0,100,20)

 #Create list to hold number of each score
 scoreList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

 #Create loop for each line in the file
 for line in lineRead:
     line = int(line)
     scoreList[line] += 1

 #create initial bar  
 x = 0
 height = scoreList[x]
 bar = Rectangle(Point(0,0),Point(15, height))
 bar.setFill("green")
 bar.setWidth(2)
 bar.draw(win)


 #create loop for drawing bars  
 for i in range(10):
     height = scoreList[x+1]
     bar = Rectangle(Point((15*x),0), Point((15*x), height))
     bar.setFill("green")
     bar.setWidth(2)
     bar.draw(win)


 main()
```

So, everything works but the for-loop. Also, I am trying to do this with no extra imports (other than math and graphics).

Here is what the text document I am getting the numbers from looks like:

[Text Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njx91.png)

So the height of each bar is the amount of times a number occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program. In this case it's impossible to tell which of your code is supposed to be inside `main()` and which is after it.

Comment: You don't seem to be incrementing `x`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: My bad, it's all in main() except the imports, I'll fix it now!

Comment: @shashwat would I put x=0+1 then x += x inside the for loop for that?

Comment: @StephenJurist change the `x` in both lines inside `#create loop for drawing bars` 's loop into `i`. That should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create initial bar for students who got zero
x = 0
y = 15
height = scoreList[x]
bar = Rectangle(Point(0,0),Point(15, height))
bar.setFill("green")
bar.setWidth(2)
bar.draw(win)


#create loop for drawing bars  
for i in range(11):

    #store x as itself +1 so it goes up 1 each loop
    x = x + 1

    #have y as iteself +15 so it goes up 15 each loop
    y = y + 15

    #the height is equal to however many times the number occured in scoreList
    height = scoreList[x]

    #Create the bar based off of the first bar and the height
    bar = Rectangle(Point(y-15,0), Point((y), height))

    bar.setFill("green")
    bar.setWidth(2)
    bar.draw(win)
```

There is my new loop which prints them just fine, but I get an index out of range error for `height = scoreList[x]` but it doesn't seem to be affecting the program.